# Setting the default selected option for the b-form-select which will be created dynamically

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-vue

I have a Vuejs application within that I am using the `Bootstrap-vue`. Some fields will be created dynamically based on the user preference.

For example, I have a `Skills` field to which users can click on the `Add` button which will show 2 drop-downs. These fields will be added dynamically to the application. I want to ensure that the all the dynamically created dropdowns have the default options selected.

If it's a direct field then I can set the `null` value and make it a default but for the dynamic cases I am not getting how to do it.

Following is the code I have:

```
<button class="btn-btn-info" @click="addSkill($event)"> Add Skill </button> 
<span v-for="skill in $store.state.skillsList" :key="skill.ID" class="form-inline">
    <span class="horizontalSpace">
        <b-form-select v-model="skillArray.skillType[skill.ID]" class="form-control" @change="addSkillInformation(skill.ID);">
            <b-form-select-option value="null" disabled>Choose</b-form-select-option>
            <b-form-select-option value="set">Set</b-form-select-option>
            <b-form-select-option value="unset">Unset</b-form-select-option>
        </b-form-select>
    </span>
</span>
```

All I want to know is how can I make the `Set` option selected for all the dropdowns which will be created dynamically based on the `Add Skill` option.

I tried `selected` but it does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your code at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj9z5mr0/). Check it. It working as wanted.

So Ill explain the code .

You need to auto select a default value mean  that **relevant data property (attached to v-model)should have a value where that value should also available in the option list**. So what I have done here is that v-model for `b-form-select` will be predefined with null values. If you dont know how many dynamic selections will be there then make that data property dynamically on at the component. Means you can initiate data at mounted/created.

**Code**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="w-100">
           <b-form-select v-for="(skill,index) in skillsList" v-model="selectedSkills[index]" class="form-control" >
            <b-form-select-option value="null" disabled>Choose</b-form-select-option>
            <b-form-select-option value="set">Set</b-form-select-option>
            <b-form-select-option value="unset">Unset</b-form-select-option>
        </b-form-select>
</div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
 data() {
      return {
        selectedSkills : ['null','null','null'],
        skillsList : ['skill 01', 'skill 02', 'skill 03'],
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I appreciate the time you took to provide the solution. In your case, you have taken 3 skills and initialized them with null values hence they will be selected by default. There isn't any `selected` option in `Bootstrap-vue` which can directly select the option? Because creating a nother function to keep track of this would end up in lot of additional code. If I have 10-15 drop-down then I need to manage them separately.